# Seeking simple INDY demo

Tags: delphi, indy10

I want a simple client server communication which I can use an underlying framework and never have to look at again. I want to concentrate on my application and have a simple functional API along the lines of:

```
SendStringFromClentToServer() : String;   // Returns the server result string
                                          // or "" on etror (or throws exception)
ProcessReceivedStringAtServer();          // And send result string
```

- I do need to know if the server replied or not; and, if so, what the result string was
- It would be nice if the serer used Indy Command Handler, but not vital as I can parse the received string myself
- also "nice to have" and where the INDY demos don't seem to cover it (except, reportedly, the SMTP demo, which I can't seem to find) would be for the server to initiate communication to the client. IF not, I can have the client poll, or have the server send its communication as a reply to the client heartbeat which I need to add.

Thanks a 1,000,000 in advance. A URL or name of an Indy 10 demo will suffice

---

Update: I really don't want my app to have to know anything about sockets (other than inditing an IP address and port number).

I don't want to know that there *is* a connection, let alone whether it is is always open or connected with each transmission request (and, if always open, I want it to auto-reopen if it closes).  At most, a boolean for those who care to indicate "keep connection open".

---

Update to the update:  Should I close this question and post another, rephrasing it better?  Surely I'm not the only one who "just wants to send some data to another PC" and doesn't really care how it is done? Isn't there an existing framework? How do you guys start each new project? Do you have a simple dummy project which handles the "plumbing" to which you add your new application? Do you know of such a thing?

Comment: [INDY 10 CLIENT SERVER DEMO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/indy10clieservr/)

Comment: This is a vague question, of no value to StackOverflow, or you, or anybody else.  You haven't asked for anything specific, only vague and undefinable things like "it should be simple".  What do you mean by having both sides initiate communication exactly? Do you mean that both sides are going to bind a socket and listen on a port? One side will listen, and accept, and once a socket is open on the "Server", either side may initiate communication?

Comment: +1 to both. Warren, the specifics are 1) I know *nothing * of sockets programming. And, if possible, I would like to keep it that way. 2) I to want to be able to send a string from one PC to an other and receive an acknowledgement that it arrived and a response/or an indication that it could be delivered. Thanks.  Now Ill go check the demo which Rudy so kindly recommended (Rudy, i hope that I don't try your patience too much).

Comment: I can tell you where that desire to keep yourself ignorant will lead you to: You'll try that, and you'll get something into production, and once it's into production, you'll learn lots of things that you will then retroactively wish you had bothered to think about, like how this thing called the internet, and how this thing called TCP/IP actually works.  Your question about having either side "initiate" for example, doesn't specify if a socket connection is closed each time a single request is completed, or kept open.  If you wanted to use SMTP as a basis for study, that would be a good start.

Comment: Rudy, some nice german error messages in the demos (fortunately I speak german). Address 0053E5DC of StringExchangeClient.exe is trying to read from address 0. I will try to muddle through the code.

Comment: Specific 3)  I don't want to know that there _is_ a connection, let alone whether it is is always open or connected with each transmission request (and, if always open, I want it to auto-reopen if it closes).  At most, a boolean for those who care to indicate "keep connection open"

Comment: Warren, another +1  I _do_ understand what you are saying, and have said the same myself to others on other topics, but I am desperately stretched and would have sacrifice something else if I need to earn sockets programming. I hope I am not sounding antagonistic, or even head in the hand stupid. I just wish for an abstraction layer which I can tell to deliver something to a given IP & port and get a reply and I don't need to care how it is done. Surely everyone wants that? Probably many, many, many have rolled their own...  Thanks, as always, for your help

Comment: So you need something like a socket.io (http://socket.io/) Delphi implementation on top of Indy that picks the transport for you and only sends messages back and forth.

Comment: BTW: You have to consider proxy servers, some corporate environments don't allow direct socket communication with the internet.

Comment: +1 (interesting question) - Is `ProcessReceivedStringAtServer();` client-side code? So you would require state management on the server as well, like in HTTP sessions?

Comment: I know your question specifically asks for an Indy 10 demo to do what you want but would you consider a web service implementation? It abstracts your communication layer and meets the "never have to look at it again" requirement. It also addresses the issue of direct socket connections that Jens brought up.

Comment: If you want the minimal effort solution then I suggest you go to a much higher level than Indy, or ICS, or Synapse.  Instead, I suggest you go look at the RemObjects SDK.

Comment: Lots of +1s. Thanks for the feedback.<br>aaa

Comment: Jens, yes, socket.io look good - pity it's JS.

Comment: Sam, I will consider anything. Maybe I need a new question(?)

Comment: Warren, Remote objects looks good, but costs $399. Do you happen to know of anything cheaper? (say, about $399 cheaper)

Comment: Nowadays, this question would be on-topic on [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)