# Seeking (free) framework for network programming

Tags: delphi, network-programming

This is an attempt to rephrase [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904896/seeking-simple-indy-demo) as a result of the feeedback which it received.

I want a simple network communication which I can use as an underlying framework and never have to look at again. I just want o push a string from one PC to another and get a string in response. I don't want to have to worry about opening conenctions, keeping them open, reopening them if they close, etc.

I want to concentrate on my application and have a simple functional API along the lines of:

```
SendStringToOtherPc() : String;   // Called at PC #1.
                                  // Returns PC #2's result string
                                  // or "" on error (or throws exception)
ProcessReceivedStringAndReply();  // Called at PC # 2. Sends result string
```

- I do need to know if the other PC replied or not; and, if so, what the result string was
- also "nice to have" would be for both PCs to initiate communication. If not, I can have one of them (the client poll), or have the other send its communication as a reply to the heartbeat which I need to add.

I presume that those with multiple fprojects under their belts have a "starter" framework which they use for every new project, just adding the application specific log - and it's such a framwork, or abstraction layer, that I want. Can anyone point me at a URL?

I know nothing of socket programming and don't really have time to learn. If I do, some other project will suffer.

While I do respect the argument that I should understand what my software is doing, there is a valid counter-arguement that everyone should not have to develop this particular wheel for himself, and surely there is some FOSS around which does what I want?

Thanks in advance.

---

Update: I seem to have started a little controversy, with some thinking me lazy or doomed to disaster. So, maybe I should explain a little of my history.

I spent three decades developing telecoms software and we always followed the [OSI 7 layer model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). I was generally layer 3, the network layer, and no matter whether it was a telephone exchange, base station or hanset, whether the protocol was ISDN, ISUP, DECT, GSM, GPRS, UMTS or a propietary satellite protocol, I could always instuct a Serveice Access Point of Layer 2, the data transport layer, "hey, you! Get this mesage to the other guy and tell me what his reply is". Did I know how it was done? Did I care?

@CosmicPrund, who will probably be awarded the answer unless someone points me at a Layer 2, said "The true answer to this question is that all you need is learn how to use Indy" and I beg to disagree.

Someone will, but not me if I can help it. I already leanred too many skills, programming languages, databse systems, oprerating systems and will always avoid learning more that an overview of another if I can. Like Sir Isaac Newton, I would prefer to stand on the shoulders of giants.

Software is just getting too big for one guy. Surely none of you start each project from scratch? I guess you reuse the networking code from a previous project(?) and that reusable code is my "Layer 2". And my question is where can I download such code and use it without understanding its inner workings?

Does anyone know of such a thing?

---

Answer: I used Indy and got what I wanted. I will porbably try to build up a library of functions which I can use as a network abstraction layer.

Comment: You can't escape dealing with connects, disconnects, latency and all the other networking related issues. The network is simply not reliable enough, it's not like you're calling a function from one unit to an other. Any decent framework will expose all of that functionality simply because any decent networked application should make the information available to the end user. That said, and given the "look" of your expected API, look into SOAP.

Comment: @Cosmin: +1 and also for the SOAP suggestion. It will allow versatility in sending stuff to the other side, while it remains possible to do "just" an WinINet or Indy HTTPGet to send a request and receive a response. The other end will be slightly more involved, but using a webbrokerbridge should be pretty light weight to implement. Sorry Mawg: don't have anything lying around to get you on your way.

Comment: I guess there is no all-purpose, 'one tool for everything' communication framework for Delphi. The implementation depends on your exact specifications - for example: do the apps only need to exchange data between these two computers, or can more computers be involved now or later? If yes, which topology is it - one computer as a central 'server' or 'master' (or 'message broker')? Or is it peer-to-peer communication, where computers can talk to each other directly?

Comment: "You can't escape dealing with connects, disconnects, latency and all the other networking related issues" - I obviously don't make my point well enough. I do undertsand that *someone* can't escape that. But I ask fo ran abstraction layer - let that handle it. I just want to code my app.

Comment: @mjn (thanks for your help on the previous question). All of those configurations - one to one, one to many, client server /master slave, peer to peer, are all just variants of "get this data to that IP address & port". I *cannot* believe that your, or anyone else's, second project statred from scratch. Surely, there is an abstraction layer?

Comment: @cosmin Yes, I suppose, I could go SOAP, but even WSDL et al seems like overkill for "get this string to IP addr X/Port Y" and get me a receipt. We are talking half a century of s/w and about two decades of Delphi. (Why) does it have to be so difficult?

Comment: It has to be, because network complexity is real.   If you knew even 5% of what actually goes on behind the scenes, at the network and mac layer, at the IP/network/routing layers, and so on, you'd be happy to return to only having to think about the socket api, and how to map that to your business requirements, and how you want to handle the error conditions that you have to handle..

Comment: @Mawg, if you email me I can send you the demo I built a couple of days ago that fits your question. And yes, I reuse exactly the same networking code for every project. At last count this was about 6 separate systems comprising about 20 distinct applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The true answer to this question is that all you need is learn how to use Indy. To prove my point I'll give you a 89 lines unit that actually implements all you requested, plus a proof-of-concept sample of how to use it.

Before I show the code I'd like to mention:

- 89 lines of code can't be called a framework. It's just a thin wrapper that's simply not worth it. Sooner or later you'd run into stuff that requires direct access to the underlying Indy framework.
- Someone with more Indy experience would probably write this using even less lines of code.
- I could even make it shorter myself, since I included two overloaded "StartServer" methods for ease of demonstration.
- Implementing this using components dropped on a form would cut the number of lines further.

Here's the "framework" unit:

```
unit UTcpIntercom;

interface

uses IdContext, IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, IdBaseComponent,
     IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, SysUtils;

type

  EIntercomError = class(Exception);
  TReceivedText = procedure(const TextFromClient:string; var Response:string) of object;
  TReceivedTextProc = procedure(const TextFromClient:string; var Response:string);

  TIntercomServer = class(TIdCustomTCPServer)
  protected
    Event: TReceivedText;
    Proc: TReceivedTextProc;
    HostGreeting: string;
  public
    function DoExecute(AContext: TIdContext): Boolean; override;
  end;

function SendTextToComputer(const TextToSend, HostToSend, HostGreeting:string; PortNumber: Integer): string;

function StartServer(PortNumber:Integer; const HostGreeting:string; OnReceivedText: TReceivedText):TIntercomServer;overload;
function StartServer(PortNumber:Integer; const HostGreeting:string; OnReceivedText: TReceivedTextProc):TIntercomServer;overload;

implementation

function SendTextToComputer(const TextToSend, HostToSend, HostGreeting:string; PortNumber: Integer): string;
var Id: TIdTCPClient;
begin
  Id := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
  try
    Id.Host := HostToSend;
    Id.Port := PortNumber;
    Id.Connect;
    try
      if Id.IOHandler.ReadLn <> HostGreeting then
        raise EIntercomError.Create('Host is invalid: ' + HostToSend);
      Id.IOHandler.WriteLn(TextToSend);
      Result := Id.IOHandler.ReadLn;
      Id.Disconnect;
    finally Id.Disconnect;
    end;
  finally Id.Free;
  end;
end;

function StartServer(PortNumber:Integer; const HostGreeting:string; OnReceivedText: TReceivedText):TIntercomServer;overload;
begin
  Result := TIntercomServer.Create(nil);
  Result.Bindings.Add.Port := PortNumber;
  Result.HostGreeting := HostGreeting;
  Result.Event := OnReceivedText;
  Result.Active := True;
end;

function StartServer(PortNumber:Integer; const HostGreeting:string; OnReceivedText: TReceivedTextProc):TIntercomServer;overload;
begin
  Result := TIntercomServer.Create(nil);
  Result.Bindings.Add.Port := PortNumber;
  Result.HostGreeting := HostGreeting;
  Result.Proc := OnReceivedText;
  Result.Active := True;
end;

{ TIntercomServer }

function TIntercomServer.DoExecute(AContext: TIdContext): Boolean;
var Text, Response: string;
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(HostGreeting);
  Text := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  Response := '';
  if Assigned(Event) then
    Event(Text, Response)
  else if Assigned(Proc) then
    Proc(Text, Response)
  else
    Response := 'No handler assigned.';
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(Response);
  AContext.Connection.Disconnect;

  Result := True;
end;

end.
```

Here's the code that uses the unit. Notice the `DoSomethingWithTextFromClient`, that's essentially your `ProcessReceivedStringAndReply` method. Also notice the use of `StartServer` and `SendTextToComputer`.

```
program Project9;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  UTcpIntercom in 'UTcpIntercom.pas';

procedure DoSomethingWithTextFromClient(const TextFromClient: string; var Response:string);
var i: Integer;
    C: Char;
    Len: Integer;
begin
  Response := TextFromClient;
  Len := Length(Response);
  for i:=1 to (Length(Response) div 2) do
  begin
    C := Response[Len-i+1];
    Response[Len-i+1] := Response[i];
    Response[i] := C;
  end;
end;

begin
  try

    try
      with StartServer(1000, 'Test', @DoSomethingWithTextFromClient) do
      begin
        WriteLn(SendTextToComputer('12345678', '127.0.0.1', 'Test', 1000));
        Free;
      end;

      Readln;

    except on E:Exception do
      begin
        WriteLn(E.ClassName);
        WriteLn(E.Message);
        Readln;
      end;
    end;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Basically I started with a few lines of code around the Indy TCP client/server connection (as above). About 8 years down the track and that 100 or so lines has grown to around 10,000 to handle generic message communication, both synchronous and asynchronous, self-reparing connectivity, etc. Like threading, unless you really want to do things from scratch and have lots of time to do this, it just makes sense to start from someone else's framework.

Comment: +1 an dmy thanks (and probably the answer, as soon as I have played around with it). Please read the bottom of the updated question to see what I am driving at.

Answer (score 4):

I have a free framework that will do all this. The benefit is that you can use it without any knowledge of sockets whatsoever. You can safely ignore connects and disconnects because this is all handled by the framework (the underlying comms framework keeps a continuous connection via configurable pings, etc). A message queueing threading model is also built into the framework. I have a demo for your exact example as well. The downside is obviously a steep learning curve. Have a look at http://www.csinnovations.com/framework_delphi.htm

Comment: How does your framework handle extended periods of network downtime?

Comment: Obviously you cannot communicate between two nodes that cannot talk to each other. The framework manages each single TCP client/server connection. If you want redundancy that is up to the design of the system architecture. Of course, the way to go is to build higher level services on top of the distributed system framework, which is what I have done, but this is not part of the free framework.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Misha. I am looking at your code now and will post my impression here. It sounds like you have understood exactly what I want. Let's hope that this is my mythical "Layer 2" ;-)

Comment: Btw, if there is a "learning curve" you relize that you will have to do what all developers hate and actually write some docuemntation if you expect others to use it :-(

Comment: @Mawg, there is a 50 page developers guide (and numerous examples). Given that the developers guide is in the Doc\DevelopersGuide directory you should have had a good look through it by now ;-)

Comment: @Mawg, BTW, I don't really care if other developers use the framework or not - it is purely a means to an end in that it helps me develop my applications and systems. Making it freely available under the MIT license is primarily to get around licensing issues when developing custom systems for clients. Putting it on the web and making it available to others is a secondary consideration, and if it helps other developers then good.